# Unity cancel OnMouseDown Event When Input Touch event triggered

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am doing levels page that you can slide to the right and left for the orher levels.

There is 6 level per page an 2d box collider every level box. When the level box is clicked, i  load the game scene by using OnMouseDown event.

But when i touch the screen to look other levels, My OnMouseDown function triggers and i couln't browse the levels through.

How can i handle this situtation.

If i touch and move the screen. I dont want to OnMouseDown function is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` returns true only during the first frame when the user *presse*s the left mouse button. However, `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` returns true while the left mouse button is being held down.

You could check whenever your input is hovering a level and add an animation to let the button feel like 'pressed in', by using `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`. Then detect an `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` and check if the input is above a level at that point. Insert the code to load your level in the `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` code.